# How can I assign the words from a specific column as a label to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi Friend I'm new here ,

Make a matrix from most repeated words in specific column `A` and add to my data frame with names of selected column as label.

#### What I have:

```
raw_data={"A":["This is yellow","That is green","These are orange","This is a pen","This is an Orange"]}
df=pr.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

#### What is my goal:

**I want to do:**

1- Separate the string & count the words in specific column

2- Make a Zero-Matrix

3- The new matrix should be labelled with founded words in step 1 (my-problem)

4- Search every row, if the word has been founded then 1 else 0

The new data frame what I have as result:

```
    A                   word_count  char_count  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   This is yellow      3           14          1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   That is green       3           13          1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
2   These are orange    3           16          0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
3   This is a pen       4           13          1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
4   This is an Orange   4           17          1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

#### What I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 1- Data frame
raw_data={"A":["This is yellow","That is green","These are orange","This is a pen","This is an Orange"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df

## 2- Count the words and characters in evrey row in columns "A"
df['word_count'] = df['A'].agg(lambda x: len(x.split(" ")))
df['char_count'] = df['A'].agg(lambda x:len(x))
df

# 3- Countung the seprated words and the frequency of repetation
df_word_count=pd.DataFrame(df.A.str.split(' ').explode().value_counts()).reset_index().rename({'index':"A","A":"Count"},axis=1)
display(df_word_count)
df_word_count=list(df_word_count["A"])
len(df_word_count)

    A       Count
0   is      4
1   This    3
2   orange  1
3   That    1
4   yellow  1
5   Orange  1
6   are     1
7   a       1
8   an      1
9   These   1
10  green   1
11  pen     1


# 4- Make a ZERO-Matrix 
allfeatures=np.zeros((df.shape[0],len(df_word_count)))
allfeatures.shape

# 5- Make a For-Loop 
for i in range(len(df_word_count)):
  allfeatures[:,i]=df['A'].agg(lambda x:x.split().count(df_word_count[i]))

# 5- Concat the data
Complete_data=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(allfeatures)],axis=1)
display(Complete_data)
```

#### What I wanted:

The Words in `"A"` in step 3 should be label of new matrix instead 0 1 2 ...

```
A   word_count          char_count  is  This orange etc.
0   This is yellow      3           14  1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   That is green       3           13  1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
2   These are orange    3           16  0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
3   This is a pen       4           13  1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
4   This is an Orange   4           17  1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed your code a little, your step 3 looks like this:

```
# 3- Countung the seprated words and the frequency of repetation
df_word_count=pd.DataFrame(df.A.str.split(' ').explode().value_counts()).reset_index().rename({'index':"A","A":"Count"},axis=1)
display(df_word_count)
list_word_count=list(df_word_count["A"])
len(list_word_count)
```

The big change is the name of a variable in `list_word_count=list(df_word_count["A"])`

the rest of the code looks like this with the new variable:

```
# 4- Make a ZERO-Matrix 
allfeatures=np.zeros((df.shape[0],len(list_word_count)))
allfeatures.shape

# 5- Make a For-Loop 
for i in range(len(list_word_count)):
  allfeatures[:,i]=df['A'].agg(lambda x:x.split().count(list_word_count[i]))

# 6- Concat the data
Complete_data=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(allfeatures)],axis=1)
display(Complete_data)
```

The only change is the different name of variable. What I do is a seventh step

```
# 7- change columns name from list
#This creates a list of the words you wanted
    l = list(df_word_count["A"])
# if you see this, it shows only the words you have in the column A
# but the result dataset that you showed you wanted, you also had some columns #that had values such as word count, etc. So we need to add that. We do this by #inserting those values you want in the list, at the beginning
    l.insert(0,"char_count")
    l.insert(0,"word_count")
    l.insert(0,"A")
    
# Finally, I rename all the columns with the names that I have in the list l
    Complete_data.columns = l
```

I get this:
[image]

Comment: Thank u for your support, but I couldn't understand what should I do exactly. Could u show me step by step what u did?